# Variable shadowing and testing for existence before assignment in javascript

Tags: javascript, shadowing

In the following code snippet I declare a global variable and then check for its presence inside a function.

```
<script>
x = 5;
$(function() {
   var x = x || 3;
   console.log(x); // prints 3
});
</script>
```

This behaves differently:

```
<script>
x = 5;
$(function() {
   var y = x || 3;
   console.log(y); // prints 5
});
</script>
```

I expect that in the first example, the variable declaration in the inner scope will detect that x already exists in the global scope, and take its value. Why does the first example 3?

Specifically I recently wrote some code that checks `var _gaq = _gaq || []` in a jQuery ready scope and was confused when nothing was getting pubbed to Analytics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `x` in the wrong scope. Due to variable hoisting, `var x` has actually defined a local `x` variable with a value of `undefined` before your `x || 3` check happens:

```
var x = x || 3;
```

is actually:

```
var x = undefined;
x = x || 3;
```

Simply change it to look for `x` on the `window` object:

```
var x = window.x || 3;
```

Comment: I should also mention that it's for this reason that I separate my variable initialization from assignment. I know that it's a little verbose to write `var foo; foo = bar;`, but it makes this particular issue stand out more noticeably.

Answer (score 1):

The first example logs 3 because 
`any variable that is initialized inside a function using the var keyword will have a local scope. If a variable is initialized inside a function without var, it will have a global scope.`

So in the first case, when the local `x` is assigned, since it is uninitialized, it gets assigned 3.

While in the second case, `x` refers to the global variable `x` as there is no declaration of `x` inside the function.

Instead, if you try this

```
<script>
x = 5;
$(function() {
   x = x || 3;
   console.log(x);
});
</script>
```

**OR**

```
<script>
x = 5;
$(function() {
   var x = window.x || 3;
   console.log(x);
});
</script>
```

you will get the expected result `5`.

Additionally, unlike C and its family (which has **block-level scope**), JavaScript has **function-level scope**. Blocks, such as if statements, do not create a new scope. Only functions create a new scope.

So if I were to write something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int x = 1;
    printf("%d, ", x); // 1
    if (1) {
        int x = 2;
        printf("%d, ", x); // 2
    }
    printf("%d\n", x); // 1
}
```

OUTPUT: **1,2,1**

as compared to

```
var x = 1;
console.log(x); // 1
if (true) {
    var x = 2;
    console.log(x); // 2
}
console.log(x); // 2
```

OUTPUT: **1,2,2**

Go through this excellent blog post on [JavaScript Scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting) to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

The `var x` in the function declares x to be local to the function, so in `x || 3` x not the global x and thus is undefined since it hasn't been initialized.

In `var y = x || 3;` x is the global x as there is no x local the function.